# C# & Visual Studio : storage issue

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a problem with Visual Studio.

When I create a new project and start programming and in between I save, at some point when I want to run it, Visual Studio does not accept my new code. It always executes the old code although I have overwritten it.

I have already re-downloaded Visual Studio 2 times but that didn't help. I use Visual Studio Community 2019

Comment: Is there a build error and you're just running the old version?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ctrl+shift+B to build it, and then running with F5, instead of Ctrl+B or F7.